# Mark all data points between two dates in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am given a table with sales and data about promotions attached to it.

When an entry has promo data filled in it means, that a promo campaign started this day for and item X. And it will end at `promo_end_date`.

Here is an example:

| date | promo_end_date | sales | item_id | promo_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.2020 | 3.1.2020 | 1 | 1 | A |
| 2.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null |
| 3.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null |
| 4.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null |
| 5.1.2020 | 6.1.2020 | 1 | 1 | B |
| 6.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null |
| 1.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null |
| 2.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null |
| 3.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null |
| 4.1.2020 | 6.1.2020 | 1 | 2 | C |
| 5.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null |
| 6.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null |

I want to create a binary column `on_promo`, which will be marking each day with promo campaigns.

So it should look like this:

| date | promo_end_date | sales | item_id | promo_id | on_promo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.2020 | 3.1.2020 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 2.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null | 1 |
| 3.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null | 1 |
| 4.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null | 0 |
| 5.1.2020 | 6.1.2020 | 1 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 6.1.2020 | null | 1 | 1 | null | 1 |
| 1.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null | 0 |
| 2.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null | 0 |
| 3.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null | 0 |
| 4.1.2020 | 6.1.2020 | 1 | 2 | C | 1 |
| 5.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null | 1 |
| 6.1.2020 | null | 1 | 2 | null | 1 |

I thought it would be done with window function, where I would partition data by `item_id` and `promo_id` and have two conditions: start date and end date. However I can't think of a way to make pyspark take a  `promo_end_date` column as an end date condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the most recent promo_end_date using `last` with `ignorenulls=True`, and then compare the date with the promo_end_date to know whether there is a current promotion:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'date', F.to_date('date', 'd.M.yyyy')
).withColumn(
    'promo_end_date', F.to_date('promo_end_date', 'd.M.yyyy')
).withColumn(
    'promo_end_date',
    F.last('promo_end_date', ignorenulls=True).over(Window.partitionBy('item_id').orderBy('date'))
).withColumn(
    'on_promo', F.when(F.col('date') <= F.col('promo_end_date'), 1).otherwise(0)
)

df2.show()
+----------+--------------+-----+-------+--------+--------+
|      date|promo_end_date|sales|item_id|promo_id|on_promo|
+----------+--------------+-----+-------+--------+--------+
|2020-01-01|    2020-01-03|    1|      1|       A|       1|
|2020-01-02|    2020-01-03|    1|      1|    null|       1|
|2020-01-03|    2020-01-03|    1|      1|    null|       1|
|2020-01-04|    2020-01-03|    1|      1|    null|       0|
|2020-01-05|    2020-01-06|    1|      1|       B|       1|
|2020-01-06|    2020-01-06|    1|      1|    null|       1|
|2020-01-01|          null|    1|      2|    null|       0|
|2020-01-02|          null|    1|      2|    null|       0|
|2020-01-03|          null|    1|      2|    null|       0|
|2020-01-04|    2020-01-06|    1|      2|       C|       1|
|2020-01-05|    2020-01-06|    1|      2|    null|       1|
|2020-01-06|    2020-01-06|    1|      2|    null|       1|
+----------+--------------+-----+-------+--------+--------+
```